# "To a sweeter more beautiful girl I could not say 'Merry Christmas'"

Tags: american-english

Does anyone know what "[To a sweeter more beautiful girl I could not say 'Merry Christmas'](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/11/16/roy-moores-lawyer-suggests-accuser-faked-signature-alabama-candidate/)" is meant to mean? I'm guessing "There's no sweeter, more beautiful girl I could say 'Merry Christmas' to" but how doe the logic go? Does it mean if there was a sweeter, more beautiful girl, I wouldn't say 'Merry Christmas' to her?

Comment: Its default reading is 'I can't imagine that there is a sweeter, more beautiful girl anywhere, and I'm privileged that she is here for me to say "Merry Christmas" to.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But how? Does it just mean 'I wouldn't say Merry Christmas to a sweeter, more beautiful girl' then?

Comment: @Clare But is it common to have the prepositional phrase at the end?

Comment: Your suggested reading is logically sound but pragmatically (especially when one looks at the flattery obviously involved) untenable. This certainly means 'There's no sweeter, more beautiful girl around ...' here. // In response to your last comment, you're now asking a different question.

Comment: He's so infatuated that he's messed up his grammar. It happens.

Answer (score 1):

What if it was meant to be a poem of sorts: 
To a sweeter, more beautiful girl I could not say, 
‘Merry Christmas.’ Love, Ray

Answer (score 0):

It's just putting the prepositional phrase first. A more common (we could say 'normal') word order is

> I could not say 'Merry Christmas' to a sweeter more beautiful girl.

The meaning is that no sweeter more beautiful girl exists for me to say 'Merry Christmas' to.

If the speaker is addressing this girl than there is an implied *than you* in the original, my rewrite, and in the  sentence giving the meaning.

Comment: Pretty basic stuff here... this answer should have been a comment, and the question closed for being... well... basic.